# ENOB of an ADC or DAC

Tags: adc, dac

When calculating an ADC or DAC ENOB, do you use SNDR or SINAD, SFDR, SNR or SDR or something else ?

I have see all used in calculating the ENOB, so which one is correct ?

Comment: [wiki says this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_number_of_bits)

Comment: Further reading: https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-003.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I use SINAD to calculate ENOB.

\begin{equation}
    \text{ENOB} =  \frac{\text{SINAD[dB]}-1.76}{6.02}
\end{equation}

The wikipedia agrees as an often used definition for ENOB : [Effective number of bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_number_of_bits)